# Adding a class to all inputs in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, filter, woocommerce

I am trying to add the Bootstrap `form-control` to all input elements in WooCommerce. I did some searching on google and came up with the found code.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'addBootstrapToCheckoutFields' );
function addBootstrapToCheckoutFields($fields) {
    foreach ($fields as &$fieldset) {
        foreach ($fieldset as &$field) {
            // add form-control to the actual input
            $field['input_class'][] = 'form-control';
        }
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

The problem is that this code only does what I want for the fields on the checkout pages. Is there a simple way to use a filter to do this for all WooCommerce fields? Obviously, I could go through every file that has fields and place the code manually, but I'd like to avoid that.

Thanks!

Comment: I have managed to do it through JQuery with `$(function(){$('input[class*="input-text"]').addClass('form-control')})` but it is not ideal.